# jenkins: can one project handle multple nodes/commands?

Tags: jenkins

I'm looking for a way to do the following:
I'd like a Project, or Pipeline, whatever it's called, to have a list of severs and a different command run on each.
Example:
server1  command1
server2  command2
server3  command3
server4  command4

I don't want to create multiple projects as the commands are nearly identical, and it's easier to manage the servers in a single project.

In creating projects, one can restrict where the project is run, however you can only select one. The servers are a mix of Win/Linux, and I don't want a Win Project and a Linux Project, but rather one project that can handle the different servers.

I guess I'm looking for a way to add multiple Selectors, with each Selector running a different command. I'm coming from a BuildForge background where this was easily possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, this is pretty straightforward with [Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/):

```
node('my-node-label') {
  sh('some-command')
}

node('my-other-node-label') {
  sh('some-other-command')
}
```